# HP folio 9470m fan error on boot

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

Once i turned on my laptop and the fan had pretty strange noise but i had a cooler connected to laptop as well. I shut it down and turned it on again and everything was okay. Today when i wanted to turn on my laptop on boot got an error about the fan. I restarted my computer and everything was okay again, the outer cooler was still connected to laptop. What could cause this problem? Is it possible that the outer cooler should not be connected before boot?

I started measuring the temeperature since then and its around 45 - 85 celsius. Is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason why you have a cooler in the first place is because you, or somebody noticed the fan problem that your laptop has. If the fan makes a strange noise, chances are there is something stuck in the fan grill or on the blades.

You can try finding a specialist to open your laptop and look at the problem. You can do it yourself. Go on YouTube and search for a video of how to repair your specific laptop, but I would advise seeing a hardware specialist so that you avoid damaging your laptop.

On the issue of the cooler being connected at startup: That does not cause any issues, as the cooler gets just power from the USB ports, and that does not have any effect on the machine!!